# Using the same DataSource by some DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu, parameters

I have a stored procedure that gets a parameter and retrieves a list of suppliers from the database:

```
Create proc spGetSuppliers
    (@RowMeterialID int)
as
begin
    select distinct sName
    from Supplier, RawMaterials, SupplierRawMaterials
    where RawMaterials.rmID = @RowMeterialID 
      and RawMaterials.rmID = SupplierRawMaterials.rmID
end
```

A datasource :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:igroup9_test1ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="spGetSuppliers" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="RowMeterialID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And about 10 DropDownList that retrieve data from the database using the DataSource.

I want the first DropDownList to use the DataSource with Value=1 which should be sent to the stored procedure and the second DDL use the value=2 and so on.